# import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken' throwing an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, node-modules, mern

when I try to import **jwt** from **jsonwebtoken** in my react app, I am getting below error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js 18:4-21     
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\swami\OneDrive\Desktop\VScode\web developement\mern-apps\basic_mern_app\front-end\client\node_modules\jsonwebtoken'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js 13:4-21   
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\swami\OneDrive\Desktop\VScode\web developement\mern-apps\basic_mern_app\front-end\client\node_modules\jsonwebtoken'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\swami\OneDrive\Desktop\VScode\web developement\mern-apps\basic_mern_app\front-end\client\node_modules\jwa'    

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js 3:13-30   
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\swami\OneDrive\Desktop\VScode\web developement\mern-apps\basic_mern_app\front-end\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js 5:13-30   
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\swami\OneDrive\Desktop\VScode\web developement\mern-apps\basic_mern_app\front-end\client\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 5:13-30 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Us
```

- I am not able to understand this error though I have installed **jsonwebtoken** properly using `npm i jsonwebtoken` .
- Now, I want to use **jwt** for the purpose of authentication without any errors.

so below is the code for my Home.js component-

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const Home = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (token) {
            const id = jwt.decode()
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Welcome to student Registration portal</h1>

            <div className="studentReg">
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="adminReg">

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Can you share your node and npm versions?

Comment: Also, how are you running your app? Please add more details.

Comment: share the code.

Comment: node version: v18.17.0
npm version:  9.6.7

I run my app using command- npm run start

Comment: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/886

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (token) {
            const id = jwt.decode(token)
        }
}, [])
```

Pass the token to jwt.decode(token) in the useEffect hook. Use jwt.verify(token) instead of jwt.decode(token).

Refer this for more information of jwt.verify() [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#:~:text=jwt.decode(token%20%5B%2C%20options%5D)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#:%7E:text=jwt.decode(token%20%5B%2C%20options%5D))